# Is removing lots of partition keys an issue if never reading them?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a Cassandra table where I'm considering deleting a lot of partitions keys. I'm aware that this will create a lot of tombstones, but can this be an issues if my read patterns is only reading rows by (non-deleted) partition keys? For example, can there be issues (I'm thinking exceptions/timeouts here, not slowness) with compaction if I have a lot of tombstones?

Comment: I don't think so, tombstones are a core feature of Cassandra from the beginning, that kind of bugs wouldn't go unnoticed all these years. Technically, I don't see any reason for exception or timeouts as it's much easier to eliminate the rows with tombstones internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're on the right track here. If you were doing a range scan i.e. gathering up all the partition keys then iterating through then you may well hit the tombstones.

You can lower the `gc_grace_seconds` on your table at a quiet time (if you have one) which should allow compaction to purge those tombstones sooner.

Keep a close eye on `nodetool tpstats` if you're changing compaction settings to make sure the compaction jobs aren't putting the nodes under too much stress.